# DELETE rows across multiple joined tables Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to `delete` rows from several tables at once in bigquery to clean my DB for further analysis.

I tried this as found here : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

```
    DELETE `test.TestLm.devc` T1, `test.TestLm.deva` T2
    FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.user_id
    WHERE is_bot IS TRUE
```

However I got :

> Syntax error: Unexpected "," at [1:40]

Any idea how to workaround this on **Bigquery** ?

### UPDATE :

Here is my complete problem, with 7 tables to delete. Is there any possibility to do it in 1 query, or in a quicker way ?

```
## 1-2 minutes :  ##
DELETE `test.TestLm.message_all` t1
WHERE relation_id IN 
(SELECT a.relation_id FROM `test.TestLm.relation_big` a 
    INNER JOIN `test.TestLm.users_big` b ON a.initier_id = b.id
    INNER JOIN `test.TestLm.users_big` c ON a.receiver_id = c.id
    WHERE (b.is_bot IS TRUE OR c.is_bot IS TRUE));

## 4+ minutes -- WARNING : WAIT UNTIL THE PREVIOUS QUERY ON 'message_all' IS FINISHED BECAUSE OF THE ABOVE JOINTURE ##
## ##
DELETE `test.TestLm.relation_big`
WHERE initier_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE)
OR receiver_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE);

## quicker queries - no need to wait ##
DELETE `test.TestLm.moderation`
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE);


DELETE `test.TestLm.report`
WHERE reporter_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE)
OR culprit_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE);

DELETE `test.TestLm.purchase_agg`
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE);

DELETE `test.TestLm.leads`
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE);

DELETE `test.TestLm.device`
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE is_bot IS TRUE);

## WARNING : !!!! WAIT UNTIL ALL PREVIOUS QUERIES ARE DONE !!!!! ##
DELETE FROM `test.TestLm.users_big` WHERE 
is_bot IS TRUE
```

Comment: I don't think BigQuery lets you delete from multiple tables at once.  It certainly does not support MySQL syntax, so you should consult the plentiful BigQuery documentation on the web.

Comment: BigQuery does not support single DELETE statement on multiple tables. Meantime, if you can clarify reasoning behind such "wish" - we can find simple workaround :o)

Comment: Thanks guys ! In my real problem I have 7 tables that can all be joined; but to avoid doing 7 queries (each of those with a painful multiple jointure) I was looking for a query that flushed all my 7 tables at once.

I just updated my post to give the real issue :)

Answer (score -1):

in standard sql mode below will work

```
DELETE test.TestLm.devc i
WHERE i.id IN (select id from test.TestLm.deva where id is not null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it'll only delete rows in table T1.
I'm trying to delete rows from both T1 & T2 at the same time.

To give some context, in my real problem I have 7 tables that can all be joined; but to avoid doing 7 queries (each of those with a painful jointure) I was looking for a query that flushed all my 7 tables at once.